# Gitlab pipeline cache not being shared due to different runners

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a simple Gitlab pipeline setup with two stages: build & test. Both stages are supposed to share cached files but they don't appear to, resulting in the test stage failing. As best I can, the problem is that each stage uses a different runner and the cached files use the runner ID as part of the path.

.gitlab-ci.ym

```
...
cache:
  key: "build"
  untracked: true
...
```

The build stage outputs the following

```
Creating cache build...
untracked: found 787 files                         
Uploading cache.zip to https://runners-cache-1.gitlab.com:443/runner/runner/30dcea4b/project/1704442/build
```

The test stage outputs the following

```
Checking cache for build...
$ mvn test
```

I believe this means the cache was NOT found because there is no download information; but it's not clear.

I can also see that each stage uses a different runner and since the runner ID is part of the cache path, I suspect that is the problem.

I need to either use the same runner for each stage or share the cache across runners. I don't understand how to do either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've been able to confirm this behavior, sometimes my build uses the same runner for both stages and then it works but when the runners are different the cache does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the [cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache) feature is appropriately named, it's only for improving build performance and is not guaranteed to have the data, much like a real cache.

The correct approach is to use [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts) with [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies).